# Jsoup android query

Tags: android, jsoup

i'm a beginner user of jsoup, i would like to use it with android sdk. 
I'm doing some testing, i would like to know how i can get a specific text in a html page.
The html code is the following:

```
<span class="time_rtq_ticker"><span id="yfs_l10_eurusd=x">1,3809</span></span>
```

I would like to get that number "1,3809" and my query using jsoup is something like this:

```
Element euro = doc.select("span[id~=yfs_l10_eurusd=x]").first();

value = euro.toString();
```

Then i display it in a textview, in this way:

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
tv.setText(value);
```

The problem is that my app show the full html code, that is:

```
<span id="yfs_l10_eurusd=x">1,3809</span>
```

How can i get only the number? Why i also get the html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Element.text()` method

```
Element euro = doc.select("span[id~=yfs_l10_eurusd=x]").first();

value = euro.text();
```